# JavaFx socket programming and send Image

Tags: java, javafx

I start programming with Javafx. in javaFx we have a class "Image" and we can load image with something like this:

```
new Image("E:/img.jpg");
```

The image class is not Serializable.
I write a messenger that we have clients and server. both of them are separate. only server access to database. clients connect to server request their information, server send to them information with `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` and client recieve them and use them. each client have an image for his/her profile. because Image is not Serializable so I save the path of image in server and server send them to client. client load image again and show it. (with code that I show earlier)
Problems is here. Loading image is not very fast and get lots of time if I have lots of clients. I have to load images specially duplicate image.

My first solution is to create a cache system that when I load profile image of a user, save it and If I need it again, use that instead of loading it again.

**My Problem is speed. If I serializable and deserializable it, is it faster or has no better performance than load image?**

But this is my solution. I want to know that is there any better and faster approach? a standard way?
I'm sorry for bad English. Any help is valuable!

Comment: I see that page now. Is it faster than load image if I serialize it or same as before?

Comment: This is probably the best answer to the question you'll get. If you think about the other part, the answer is simply "No", since you need to get the information to your clients at least once so the least amount of data transmitted happens if you transmit the data exactly once. Store all the image data a client has used before locally on the client file system and check there first, you only transmit the images once. You do need to transmit some kind of identifier to allow for changes of profile pictures, so this amount of data is also necessary.

Comment: thanks for answer.